# Add strong typing for react navigation props

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using typescript in my react-native project(expo).

The project uses react-navigation, so on my screens I can set `navigationOptions` and I have access to the prop `navigation`.

Now I'm trying to strongly type these so I get hints for what properties are available to set.

```
interface NavStateParams {
    someValue: string
}

interface Props extends NavigationScreenProps<NavStateParams> {
   color: string
}

class Screen extends React.Component<Props, any> {
    // This works fine
    static navigationOptions: NavigationStackScreenOptions = {
        title: 'ScreenTitle'
    }
    // Does not work
    static navigationOptions: NavigationStackScreenOptions = ({navigation, screenProps }) => ({
        title: navigation.state.params.someValue
    })
}
```

What would be the best way to handle react-navigation as props for components.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just add NavigationType to your Props, like this:

```
    import { StackNavigator, NavigationScreenProp } from 'react-navigation';

    export interface HomeScreenProps {
      navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any,any>
    };

    export class HomeScreen extends React.Component<HomeScreenProps, object> {

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>       
            <Button
              title="Go to Details"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: But then I would have to provide the `navigation` props if I were to import the `HomeScreen` component from other components(say, `App.tsx`). How can I avoid it?

Comment: In your top component, use the withNavigation function to supply these props
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html

Comment: I haven't figured out a way to use `withNavigation` with typescript, either, because it also requires an extra navigation prop. I have another question about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585890/how-to-use-react-navigations-withnavigation-in-typescript

Comment: All this does is provide types for `props.navigation` within instance methods, which was already achieved in the original question. The question is asking 1) How to get types for `navigation` within the `navigationOptions` static method, and 2) How to get types for the parameters that are available in the navigation state.

Comment: After adding navigation to props as shown above I exported my component as `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withNavigation(MyComponent));` and that resolved the typescript complaint that `MyComponent` was missing props

Comment: NavigationScreenProp is not supported in ver >= 6.x

Comment: `any` is not a "strong" typing...

Answer (score 43):

if you are passing the `navigation` prop that is defined by

```
let navigation = useNavigation()
```

to a component, the best way of typing is:

```
import {NavigationProp, ParamListBase} from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>
```

**Update:**

Here is a better approach for strong navigation typing, using the latest `@react-navigation` version (`6.x`)

full example:

```
import {NativeStackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

type RootStackParamList = {

   ScreenOne: undefined; //current screen

   ScreenTwo: {slug: string}; // a screen that we are 
// navigating to, in the current screen,
// that we should pass a prop named `slug` to it

   ScreenThree: {data: Array<string>};

   ScreenFour: undefined; // a screen that we are navigating to 
// in the current screen, that we don't pass any props to it
};

interface IPageProps {
   navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'ScreenOne'>;
}

// Since our screen is in the stack, we don't need to 
// use `useNavigation()` to provide the `navigation` to
// our component, we just need to read it as a prop

function Pdp({navigation}: IPageProps) {
   return ...
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMO. Simple and work like a charm

Comment: this seems perfect but can you add a minimal detail example. It will be very helpful

Comment: @AliYarKhan I provided a better approach that matches the latest updates of `react-navigation`  in version `6.x`

Comment: Is there a solution like this with the generic @react-navigation/stack? In other words, is this solution only possible using the native-stack module and why?

Answer (score 14):

A minimal configuration, with version 6.x

```
import { NavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/native";

interface RouterProps {
    navigation: NavigationProp<any, any>;
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
    <Text>Navigate to Home</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: `any` is not a "strong" typing...

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: NavigationScreenProps) => ({
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue, and here's my solution:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { NavigationScreenProps, NavigationStackScreenOptions } from 'react-navigation'

interface NavStateParams {
  someValue: string
}

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
type NavigationOptionsFn<TParams=any> = (props: NavigationScreenProps<TParams>) => NavigationStackScreenOptions

class Screen extends React.Component {
  // This should works fine
  static navigationOptions: NavigationOptionsFn<NavStateParams> = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.someValue
  })
}
```

You may want to declare `NavigationOptionsFn<TParams>` type into some `d.ts` file to make it work globally.

Answer (score 4):

I think with `react-navigation` 5.X it's simpler now. Here is how to type hint `navigation` props passed to screens/components:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component<{
    navigation: StackNavigationHelpers;
}> {
...
}
```

Ps: Tested with these versions

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.2.3",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.1",
```

Comment: How do we invoke `navigation.setOptions()` in this case? It says `Property 'setOptions' does not exist on type 'StackNavigationHelpers'`

Comment: @highjump yeah correct, need to look for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
 yarn add --dev @types/jest @types/react-navigation

import { NavigationScreenProps } from "react-navigation";

export interface ISignInProps extends NavigationScreenProps<{}> { userStore: IUserStore }

export class SignInScreen extends React.Component { .... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static navigationOptions: NavigationScreenConfig<NavigationStackScreenOptions> = 
    ({navigation}) => ({/* Your options... */})
```

Comment: Its best solution for navigationOptions its support arrow function and object, thanks, also note use `NavigationScreenOptions` instead of `NavigationStackScreenOptions`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still experiencing this issue while extending `NavigationScreenProps` so you can correctly type `navigationOptions` etc along with your own props:

```js
interface Props extends NavigationScreenProps {
  someProp: string;
  anotherProp: string;
}

export const SomeGreatScreen: NavigationScreenComponent<NavigationParams, {}, Props> = ({
  someProp,
  anotherProp,
}) => {
...
};
```

Whereas `NavigationScreenComponent<Props>` resulted in type errors for the destructured properties `{ someProp, anotherProp }`, not recognizing the extension to the props, `NavigationScreenComponent<NavigationParams, {}, Props>` did. This appears to be due to the need to send the extended props type as the third parameter:

```js
  export type NavigationScreenComponent<
    Params = NavigationParams,
    Options = {},
    Props = {}
  > = React.ComponentType<NavigationScreenProps<Params, Options> & Props> & {
    navigationOptions?: NavigationScreenConfig<Options>;
  };
```

> from [`react-navigation.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a67c19be85df49fd923b8175beb7f1c75c2e5c24/types/react-navigation/index.d.ts#L234-L240)

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution

First **add RootStackParamList type and PageProps interface** to your navigator files

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createNativeStackNavigator,
  NativeStackNavigationProp,
} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import HomeScreen from './screens/Home';
import PasswordAddScreen from './screens/PasswordAdd';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined; // Add your props here
  PasswordAdd: undefined;
};

export interface PageProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> { // T is one of Home|PasswordAdd
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, T>;
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function Navigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="PasswordAdd" component={PasswordAddScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default Navigator;
```

**Then, in your Component or Screen file add**

```
import React from 'react';
import { PageProps } from '../../Navigator';

function ItemsSeparator() {
  return <Divider my={1} bgColor="coolGray.50" />;
}

type Props = PageProps<'Home'>; // import and use the PageProps and pass the screen name - 
                                // exactly as it is in RootStackParamList

function HomeScreen({ navigation }: Props) {
  return (
    <Box safeArea bgColor="coolGray.100">
     ...
    </Box>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than describing manually all your [navigation functions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html) (e.g: navigate), in your Props' interface, you can directly extends `NavigationScreenProps`.

In my case it was mandatory to stop eslint from yielding an error.

```
import { StackNavigator, NavigationScreenProps } from 'react-navigation';

export interface HomeScreenProps extends NavigationScreenProps {
/* your custom props here */
};

export class HomeScreen extends React.Component<HomeScreenProps, object> {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>       
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
public static navigationOptions: NavigationScreenOptionsGetter<
  NavigationScreenOptions
> = (navigation, stateProps) => ({
  title: navigation.state.params.someValue,
});
```

Comment: It seems the NavigationScreenOptionsGetter was made for this purpose, but it doesn't work. As you can see here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html the navigationOptions function takes an object.

Answer (score 0):

The `does not work` section contains an error if your `tsconfig.json` has `"strictNullChecks": true`. In this case, you have an error indeed, because in the line

`navigation.state.params.someValue`

`params` is optional. What you could do is to check if the value was passed inside and provide default one otherwise, like:

`title: navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.someValue || 'Default title'`

Answer (score 0):

or if You want to make a Custome hook and Export it
here is how you can do it

```
import {
  NavigationProp,
  ParamListBase,
  useNavigation,
} from "@react-navigation/native";

export const useAppNavigation: () => NavigationProp<ParamListBase> = useNavigation;
```

and to use it

IMPORT useAppNavigation FROM Your PATH and then use as

```
const navigation = useAppNavigation();

const onPressSignUp = () => {
  navigation.navigate("SignUp");
};
```