# How to use react-navigation's withNavigation in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use react-native, react-navigation and typescript together to create an app. There are only two screens(`HomeScreen` and `ConfigScreen`) and one component(`GoToConfigButton`) in total, as follows.

#### HomeScreen

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationScreenProps } from "react-navigation";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import GoToConfigButton from "./GoToConfigButton";

export class HomeScreen extends React.Component<NavigationScreenProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Click the following button to go to the config tab.</Text>
        <GoToConfigButton/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

#### GoToConfigButton

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";
import { NavigationInjectedProps, withNavigation } from "react-navigation";

class GoToConfigButton extends React.Component<NavigationInjectedProps> {
  render() {
    return <Button onPress={this.handlePress} title="Go" />;
  }
  private handlePress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Config");
  };
}
export default withNavigation(GoToConfigButton);
```

The code for `ConfigScreen` is not given because it's not important here. Well, actually the above code works, I can go to the config screen by clicking on the button. The problem is, Typescript thinks I should provide the `navigation` property to `GoToConfigButton` manually.

```
<View>
  <Text>Click the following button to go to the config tab.</Text>
  <GoToConfigButton/>  <-- Property "navigation" is missing.
</View>
```

How can I tell Typescript that the `navigation` property is given automatically by `react-navigation`?

Comment: It looks like the withNavigation function should strip out the NavigationInjectedProps interface. 

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-navigation/index.d.ts#L1173

It shouldn't matter, but can you try changing 
  class GoToConfigButton extends React.Component<NavigationInjectedProps> {
to
  class GoToConfigButton extends React.Component<{} & NavigationInjectedProps> {

Comment: @AndrejKyselica works! but how? why? what is the difference between `React.Component<NavigationInjectedProps>` and `React.Component<{} & NavigationInjectedProps> `

Answer (score 4):

You were just missing Partial<> interface wrapping your NavigationInjectedProps as it is described in this [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29208) where this issue was fixed.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";
import { NavigationInjectedProps, withNavigation } from "react-navigation";

class GoToConfigButton extends React.Component<Partial<NavigationInjectedProps>> {
    render() {
        return <Button onPress={this.handlePress} title="Go" />;
    }

    private handlePress = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Config");
    };
}

export default withNavigation(GoToConfigButton);
```

Tested with [@types/react-navigation >= 2.13.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-navigation)

Comment: This doesn't work. I can't pass the component to this function.

Comment: Doesn't work with `react-navigation 4.4.4` and `react 17`

Answer (score 2):

```js
import styles from "./styles";

import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import {
  DrawerItems,
  NavigationInjectedProps,
  SafeAreaView,
  withNavigation
} from "react-navigation";

class BurgerMenu extends PureComponent<NavigationInjectedProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} >

        <Button
          icon={{ name: "md-log-out", type: "ionicon" }}
          title={loginStrings.logOut}
          iconContainerStyle={styles.icon}
          buttonStyle={styles.button}
          titleStyle={styles.title}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(BurgerMenu);
```